# Getting Data in my Laravel Server from Android APP via Json

Tags: php, android, json, laravel, laravel-5

So, I'm building a Laravel Aplication for my Android APP.

I'll send a Json from Android and I need do recieve this in my laravel Aplication.

How can I manage this?

How Can I build this Route and this Controller function?

```
Route::get('/json', 'JsonController@json' );
```

So, What should I do in this "JsonController" do work with this Json

Comment: Please post your code , whatever you have done

Comment: I dont have any kind of code wich will help in my question.

Comment: i'm like without know where should I start

Comment: Laravel system will get data by either GET method or POST method

So Route should be Route::any('url', 'ControllerName@methodName');

and the value you can get inside the controller using $jsonPostedData = Input::get('parametername');

Comment: I've post a route example

Comment: Laravel system will get data by either GET method or POST method So Route should be Route::post('url', 'ControllerName@methodName'); and the value you can get inside the controller using $jsonPostedData = Input::get('parametername');

Answer (score 1):

I used this route:

```
Route::get('jsontest', 'JsonController@jsonFunction');
```

and called this function and worked. Thank for Help from @NIRANJAN

```
   public function jsonFunction(){

        $jsonPostedData = Input::all();
        return $jsonPostedData;
    }
```